# Password hashing when registering a user

Tags: security, authentication, web

I know there are similar questions but I couldn't find something that answered my question.

When a new user registers (client - server) is there a common way of protecting these details when they are sent?

At the moment I am just concatenating the username-password-timestamp then sending as Base64 to the server over https.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The common and best way is https. Https already establishes a secure channel between the client and the server. You don't need anything more.

Please excuse me for the short answer. However if you really want the long answer then take a look at:
 [How to send password securely via HTTP using Javascript in absence of HTTPS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2003262/how-to-send-password-securely-via-http-using-javascript-in-absence-of-https)