# How to Extract body request node.js

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, mongodb, postman

I have just started learning node.js (Express) and I created a simple application that communicate with a very simple mongo database. I have a collection called 'Users' in a database called 'testDB'. I created my skeleton in my node.js application and I followed 'separation of concern' logic.

In my controller folder I have a subfolder called usersController. Inside that subfolder, there is 2 .js files, one is usersControllers.js and the other is usersRoutes.js

Inside usersRoutes.js there is the following code:

```
    "use strict";
    var express = require('express');
    var router = express.Router();

    // require the controller here
    var usersController = require("./usersController.js")();


    router
        .get('/', usersController.getAllUsers)
        .post('/', usersController.createUser);

    module.exports = router;
```

As you can see, I am calling a function (factory) that is inside usersController.js called 'createUser'. This function is written like the following:

```
"use strict";

var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

var usersController = function(){
    var getAllUsers = function(req, res){
        MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost/testDB', function(err, db){
            if(err){
                throw err;
            }
            db.collection('Users').find().toArray(function(err, doc){
                if(err){
                    throw err;
                }
                else{
                    return res.status(200).json(doc);
                    db.close();
                }
            });

        });
    };

    var createUser = function (req, res) {
        MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost/testDB', function(err, db){

            console.log(req.body);
            db.close();
        });
    };

    return {
        getAllUsers: getAllUsers,
        createUser: createUser
    };
};
module.exports = usersController;
```

I have created a post man request to explore how to extract the body data that I am sending. The request is like the following

In the header I have 2 keys

- Accept: application/json;charset=UTF-8
- Content-Type: application/json

In the body I have the following raw text:

```
{
    "Users": {
        "First Name": "Ahmed",
        "Last Name": "Rahim",
        "Username": "rahima1",
        "Passwoed": "secure"
    }
}
```

Based on the previous scenario, I have a few questions:

1. How to extract the body from the request. I tried to dig into 'req'
   but I couldn't find what I am looking for?
2. passing a plain password like that is not good, right? Any
   suggestions to pass an encrypted password (maybe sha)?
3. Is there something wrong in the request itself?

Any side note will help me a lot from experts like you guys :)

Thank you all!!

Comment: First, it's better to make one question per time. Second, what's exactly the problem?

Comment: I am trying to send a postman request (POST) and then in node I am trying to get the body request that I sent

Comment: 1. You need a [bodyparser](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser) to get the data. 2. It's okay to send the password as plain text.

Comment: Ok.. I will take a look at the bodyparser thing.. is it something I require (is it a module)? how to include it ?

Comment: Yes, it's a module, and no, it's not required, you could write your own code, but if you want the data automagically populated in `req.body` it's required.

Comment: I did that.. but it did not work :(

Answer (score 1):

You need to import and require [body-parser](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser)

```
npm install body-parser
```

and

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
...
app.use(bodyParser.json());
```

Answer (score 0):

> How to extract the body from the request. I tried to dig into 'req' but I couldn't find what I am looking for?

This should be done with a simple `req.body`. From the [express docs](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html) on `req.body`:
"Contains key-value pairs of data submitted in the request body. By default, it is undefined, and is populated when you use body-parsing middleware such as body-parser and multer."

> passing a plain password like that is not good, right? Any suggestions to pass an encrypted password (maybe sha)?

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2003262/how-to-send-password-securely-via-http-using-javascript-in-absence-of-https) sums it up pretty well. If you want to reliably encrypt password submission, you **need** to use https.

Comment: I tried req.body but it is giving me undefined .. that's why I decided to post this question :)

Comment: Ah i see that you're using req.body... guess I overlooked that. Is the result of that undefined? I'm not certain what your problem there is.

Comment: yup .. when I call req.body.. it will give me 'undefined' for some reason :(

Comment: Yea, sorry that's my bad. My guess is there's a problem in the request you're making. Possibly you are not sending a POST request? If the request is correct that should basically work magically.

Comment: That's true .. it should work.. I made sure that my request type is 'POST' and the url is correct.. HOWEVER, I don't know if the body style is correct .. should I choose 'form-data' instead on 'raw'

Comment: The body should be 'application/json'

Comment: hmm.. I know that you can pass that in the header as a 'key' in postman, right?

Comment: @Riad, are you using express?

Answer (score 0):

I read the comments etc, and realize you haven't found a solution yet.

I can't really seem to find your actual mistake, but would like to provide some code example, that could possibly help you find it yourself.

Btw in your sent object, I wouldn't write "Users" with capital "U", but just "users".

So lets say we have this router file, that could be your createUser. It should look something like this:

```
router.post('createUser', function (req, res) {
  var users = req.body.users;
  res.json(users);
});
```

This should sent just what you have sent :-) Try and do that before you start talking with a database. That way you will can easily confirm that what you send is what you the server receives. Hope it is any help, else I am happy to assist you, if you have further questions .