# How to pass an action name using hyperlink in Struts 2?

Tags: java, jquery, jsp, validation, struts2

I have a hyperlink named `"Click for new User"`. Once I click the link, I got `NullPointerException` instead of opening `RegisterPage.jsp` page.

I post my code here, I can't find my mistake

**`index.jsp`:**

```
<s:form action="verify">
<s:textfield name="username" key="label.uname"  required="true"/>
<s:password name="password" key="label.pass" required="true"/>
<s:submit value="Login" align="center"/> 
</s:form>
<a href="<s:url action='register'/>">Click for New User</a>
```

**`struts.xml`:**

```
<struts>
<package name="a" extends="struts-default">
<action name="verify" class="java4s.Login"  method="execute">
<result name="success">loginsuccess.jsp</result>
<result name="error">error.jsp</result>
<result name="input">index.jsp</result>
</action>
<action name="register" class="java4s.Login" method="register">
<result name="success">RegisterPage.jsp</result>
</action>
</package>
</struts>
```

**`Login.java`(Action Class):**

```
package java4s;

import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;

public class Login extends ActionSupport {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private String username,password;
public String getUsername() {
    return username;
}
public void setUsername(String username) {
    this.username = username;
}
public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}
public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}
public String register(){
    System.out.println("register ()");
    return SUCCESS;
}
public String execute(){
    if (getUsername().equals("java4s")&&getPassword().equals("java4s")) {
        return SUCCESS;
    } else {
        this.addActionError(getText("u.p.wrong"));
        return ERROR;
    }   
}
@Override
public void validate() {
        if (getUsername().equals("")||getUsername().length()==0)
        this.addFieldError("username",getText("error.uname"));
        if(getPassword().equals("")||getPassword().length()==0) 
        this.addFieldError("password", getText("error.pass"));

}
}
```

**Exception:**

```
 javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NullPointerException
 org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:515)
 org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher.doFilter(FilterDispatcher.java:4‌​19)
 java.lang.NullPointerException
java4s.Login.validate(Login.java:38)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.doIntercept(DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.java:200)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:86)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:224)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:223)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.profiling.UtilTimerStack.profile(UtilTimerStack.java:455)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:221)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.ValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(ValidationInterceptor.java:150)
org.apache.struts2.interceptor.validation.AnnotationValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(AnnotationValidationInterceptor.java:48)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:86)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:224)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:223)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.profiling.UtilTimerStack.profile(UtilTimerStack.java:455)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:221)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ConversionErrorInterceptor.intercept(ConversionErrorInterceptor.java:123)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:224)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:223)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.profiling.UtilTimerStack.profile(UtilTimerStack.java:455)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:221)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:167)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:86)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:224)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:223)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.profiling.UtilTimerStack.profile(UtilTimerStack.java:455)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:221)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.StaticParametersInterceptor.intercept(StaticParametersInterceptor.java:105)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:224)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:223)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.profiling.UtilTimerStack.profile(UtilTimerStack.java:455)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:221)
org.apache.struts2.interceptor.CheckboxInterceptor.intercept(CheckboxInterceptor.java:83)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:224)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:223)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.profiling.UtilTimerStack.profile(UtilTimerStack.java:455)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:221)
org.apache.struts2.interceptor.FileUploadInterceptor.intercept(FileUploadInterceptor.java:207)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:224)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:223)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.profiling.UtilTimerStack.profile(UtilTimerStack.java:455)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:221)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ModelDrivenInterceptor.java:74)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:224)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:223)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.profiling.UtilTimerStack.profile(UtilTimerStack.java:455)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:221)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.java:127)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:224)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:223)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.profiling.UtilTimerStack.profile(UtilTimerStack.java:455)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:221)
org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ProfilingActivationInterceptor.intercept(ProfilingActivationInterceptor.java:107)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:224)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:223)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.profiling.UtilTimerStack.profile(UtilTimerStack.java:455)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:221)
org.apache.struts2.interceptor.debugging.DebuggingInterceptor.intercept(DebuggingInterceptor.java:206)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:224)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:223)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.profiling.UtilTimerStack.profile(UtilTimerStack.java:455)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:221)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ChainingInterceptor.intercept(ChainingInterceptor.java:115)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:224)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:223)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.profiling.UtilTimerStack.profile(UtilTimerStack.java:455)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:221)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.I18nInterceptor.intercept(I18nInterceptor.java:143)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:224)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:223)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.profiling.UtilTimerStack.profile(UtilTimerStack.java:455)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:221)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.PrepareInterceptor.doIntercept(PrepareInterceptor.java:121)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:86)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:224)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:223)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.profiling.UtilTimerStack.profile(UtilTimerStack.java:455)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:221)
org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ServletConfigInterceptor.intercept(ServletConfigInterceptor.java:170)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:224)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:223)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.profiling.UtilTimerStack.profile(UtilTimerStack.java:455)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:221)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.AliasInterceptor.intercept(AliasInterceptor.java:123)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:224)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:223)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.profiling.UtilTimerStack.profile(UtilTimerStack.java:455)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:221)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ExceptionMappingInterceptor.intercept(ExceptionMappingInterceptor.java:176) 
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:224)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:223)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.profiling.UtilTimerStack.profile(UtilTimerStack.java:455)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:221)
org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.execute(StrutsActionProxy.java:50)
org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:504)
org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher.doFilter(FilterDispatcher.java:419)
```

Comment: Where is NPE coming from?

Comment: @AleksandrM Perhaps it come from struts.xml file,i post my exception here javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NullPointerException
 org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:515)
 org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher.doFilter(FilterDispatcher.java:419)

Comment: I have added your exception to your post. In the future please add all relevant details to your question and not as unformatted comments. Further, what's with the unindented XML? It's not exactly easy to read. And finally, that isn't the full stacktrace. Please post the **full** stacktrace.

Comment: Which version of Struts2?

Comment: @AleksandrM struts2.0

Comment: Look at the jar file (e.g. struts2-core-x.x.x.jar). What is x.x.x in your case?

Comment: @AleksandrM struts2-core-2.0.11.jar

Comment: Why are you using such old version? Current latest is 2.3.15.1.

Comment: yeah ur right,But currently i doing project in struts2.0 next project,i will move on latest version of the struts

Comment: Do you have `Login` class in `java4s` package?

Comment: can you provide more log information or is it only part being shown by server? and what page/message you are getting when clicking on link? are you getting server error message page?

Comment: @AleksandrM yes,i having Class in java4s.Login

Comment: @UmeshAwasthi i post the Error message,please look at my post...

Comment: NPE `java4s.Login.validate(Login.java:38)`.

Comment: `java4s.Login.validate(Login.java:38)`, can you also show your action class? are you doing nay sort of validation there?

Comment: @Krish: Could you post your `Login` class `validate` method.

Comment: @AleksandrM please look at my post,i post my Action Class(Login)

Comment: when you are calling your action by link, there are no username and password field and you are doing validation over them by checking there length and empty value which is causing this issue, since your validate method is being called due to interceptor stack configured by S2

Comment: And not checking for null.

Comment: @UmeshAwasthi please look at my post,i post my Action Class(Login)

Comment: i will suggest you to use Apache common library for all such case and it's String Util method `StringUtils.isBlank()` is null safe check which will be able to solve your issue and more over common is really a helpful API in many aspects

Comment: @UmeshAwasthi is there is any way to segregate the field and link?

Comment: I am not sure why you are using validate method while you can either use build in validation framework which is more flexible and provide more details, also as suggested validate method will be triggered each time you action's method is being called due to default stack configured, so either you can create a separate action for registration or u can check for null values in your action class

Comment: @UmeshAwasthi in my action class i set a condition to check the empty string  in validate() please look at my code.

Comment: that will throw a null pointer exception when your username is not being set as in that case it will be null and performing any action over null value will throw NPE. what i said that `StringUtils.isBlank()` is null safe which means it will first check if given value is not null and only after that it will check if string is empty or not.

Comment: @Krish: Read this: http://struts.apache.org/development/2.x/docs/validation.html.

Comment: @AleksandrM i worked in declarative validation(XML validation),now i try in programatic validation(Manual validation).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you click on hyperlink you don't supply the request URL with parameters `username` and `password` (the parameters aren't set by the `params` interceptor), so the values of this properties are `null` but the `validate()` method is called before the action is executed because your action extend `ActionSupport` which implemented `Validateable` and `ValidationAware` that allows the `validation` interceptor (which is a part of the `defaultStack`) execute `validate()` method where you could perform manual checks and provide `ActionErrors`, `FieldErrors`, and `ActionMessages`. But there's no reason to do so if you don't provide the values for the properties. You should either submit the form or set the parameters in the url like

```
<a id="myLink" href="#">Click for New User</a>
<script type="text/javascript>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#myLink').click(function(e) {
    window.location="<s:url action='register'/>"+"?username="+$('username').val()+"&password="+$('password').val();
    return false;
  });
});
</script>
```

But the problem is the parameter values (username and password) are sensitive information and shouldn't pass in the URL. And you should use either Ajax `post` or submit the form with the `POST` request like in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16376190/hide-passed-parameter-from-jsp-to-struts2-action-class/16384229#16384229) example.

When using manual validations very useful to utilize the [Apache commons validator](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-validator/)

```
if (GenericValidator.isBlankOrNull(value))
  addFieldError("FieldLabel", MessageFormat.format(getText("ErrorKey"),
    getText("FieldLabel"), new Object {}));
```

The similar code could be done for `ActionErrors` and/or `ActionMessages`. Other validators are available in the commons-validator package, or you could use Struts2 validators that is out of this question.

Comment: i am sorry for unaccept ur answer, the problem is my workspace,in my workspace having 12 project,so it could not be properly work,during restarting time only ur code will be work,thanks for reply my post.