# How to exclude particular action name (servlets) from Spring MVC Request mapping so that it looks for that action into web.xml

Tags: java, spring-mvc, struts2, action-mapping

In Struts I have used

```
<constant name="struts.action.excludePattern" value="/servlet-action"/>
```

Doing above, Struts avoids looking for `/servlet-action` into `struts.xml` and goes to `web.xml`.

How to achieve this in Spring MVC?

Or can `@RequestMapping` be done for servlets?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this if you map Spring MVC servlet to either than a default servlet. Then it could be handled by the servlet container.

To exclude some patterns from the mapping you can use url rewrite filter. You can read more about this in my answer to [How can URL rewriting in Struts2.x](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25259936/573032).