# How to pass parameters to an action by a post or ajax call in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, struts2

My intent is to pass a couple of parameters to an action in struts2, but I want that these parameters have to be hidden, so the GET call is not recommended. I thought that a post or ajax call in jQuery could be a good idea to do so, but the parameters are null and the redirect to the jsp page doesn't work. Here are the Action and the javascript codes:

MyAction.java

```
public class MyAction extends ActionSupport{

     private Long pkId;
     private String type;

     public String execute() {
        String pkId = getPkId();
        String type = getType();
        return Action.SUCCESS;
     }
}
```

file.js

```
function myFunction(){
    var pkId = "pkId1";
    var url = "./myAction.action";
    var type = "type1";
    $.ajax(url, {pkId : pkId, type : type});
}
```

---

Updated code:

```
function myFunction(){
        var pkId = "pkId1";
        var url = "./myAction.action";
        var type = "type1";
        $.post(url, {pkId : pkId, type : type}, function(resp){
             // resp is the response from the server after the post request.
        });
    }
```

---

Comment: You didn't specify that you wanted a `POST` request. The default for a `$.ajax()` call is `GET`. Specify the `method` as explained in the doco.

Comment: possible duplicate of [hide passed parameter from jsp to struts2 action class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16376190/hide-passed-parameter-from-jsp-to-struts2-action-class)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have done is right. Instead of the `$.ajax()`, use the `$.post` shortform:

```
$.post(url, {pkId : pkId, type : type}, function (resp) {
  // resp is the response from the server after the post request.
});
```

So the `file.js` contains:

```
function myFunction() {
    var pkId = "pkId1";
    var url = "./myAction.action";
    var type = "type1";
    $.post(url, {pkId : pkId, type : type}, function (resp) {
      // resp is the response from the server after the post request.
    });
}
```

---

If you don't want an Asynchronous request, make it a default form.

```
function myFunction() {
    var pkId = "pkId1";
    var url = "./myAction.action";
    var type = "type1";
    var FormD = '<form method="post" action="' + url + '" id="frmFakeSubmit">';
    FormD += '<input type="hidden" name="pkId" value="' + pkId + '" />';
    FormD += '<input type="hidden" name="type" value="' + type + '" />';
    FormD += '</form>';
    $("body").append(FormD);
    $("#frmFakeSubmit").submit();
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I edited my code like you suggested; the parameters are passed correctly but the redirect to the jsp page after the success of my action doesn't work. I don't know what I have to put into the function method.

Comment: Where do you wanna redirect? Do you wanna redirect to `"./myAction.action"`?

Comment: Yes, I want to redirect to my action with the two parameters filled.

Comment: @chris Then you should not use AJAX. AJAX is only for Asynchronous. Lemme update my answer.

Comment: @chris Have a look now!

Answer (score 0):

```
 $.ajax({
     url: "<your url>",
     type: "POST",
     data: JSON.stringify(<your data>)
 }).done(function(response) {
    //TODO response from the sever
 });
```

Since the default request method of `$.ajax` is GET, you should specify the type parameter as 'POST' to do a `post` request.