# Secure register API Cross Origin

Tags: php, angularjs, laravel, security, laravel-5.3

## Secure register API Cross Origin

---

**Some info**

On my internship I'm making a spotify like application. I'm doing the server-side with a laravel API while the other intern is making the client-side with an Ionic/Angularjs app.

---

**Problem**

Is it safe to send the password and username with an `POST`request.
On the server-side its encrypted but while its being send its not.

And if its not safe, does anyone know a safe way of doing this.

*I Was thinking about hashing the login and then send it but is this really safe?*

---

Thanks in advance and sorry for the bad english.

Comment: Why don't you use the token authentication provided by Laravel out-of-the box? Check the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/passport) for more info

Comment: Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1582894/how-to-send-password-securely-over-http) post about security can help you out.

Comment: I'm using it. But for the first login you still have to send the raw data

Comment: Run everything over HTTPS, job done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up using HTTPS. This would make it secure enough.

---

For future reference, you should probably look at OAuth.