# API Request Method

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, api

```
var settings = {
  "async": true,
  "crossDomain": true,
  "url": "https://urlexampleapi.com",
  "method": "GET",
  "headers": {
    "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    "Accept": "application/json",
    "appKey": "mykeyhere",
    "appToken": "mytokenhere"
  }
}

$.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
  console.log(response);
});
```

Hi everyone, I want to make this request to a certain api, but I know that is insecure to pass my credentials on header.
What would be the best practice to apply on this case?
Any suggestion would be appreciated

Thanks!

Comment: It is insecure to use `http:`, period.  Other than that, it depends on your threat model.  For example, do you mind exposing your API key to the world?

Comment: My guess is the api probably isn't even CORS enabled so that you don't go exposing your credentials in a browser Use a proxy on a server you control to make the request and keep your credentials out of public view

Comment: Sorry I forgot to put the s on the url.

Answer (score 0):

You can prefer using https and other approach are mentioned in the following question

[how-to-send-password-securely-over-http](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1582894/how-to-send-password-securely-over-http)